# IOS Porting from Android

Tags: ios, frameworks

I have a working Android app that I'd like to port to IOS. I've started working through the Apple API references and am hopeful I can get some quick assistance.

Based on a specific time of day, I'd like to ideally toggle airplane mode so that the user cannot send or receive emails or calls. I appreciate that this can only be accomplished using private APIs which I want to avoid. As such, what other options are available to mimic the end result as closely as possible? Could the app turn off all notifications, or turn the screen off, or set brightness to zero, or disable the pop-up keyboard.

Knowing that Apple has locked down system wide settings, is there another creative idea that could I could employ?

Answer (score 0):

No. Apple does not allow 3rd party apps to alter global settings like Airplane mode. Apps operate in a very limited "sandbox" where they have very limited access to system resources.

What you describe is not possible unless your app is running on a jailbroken (rooted, in Android terms) device.